# How to make flexbox child not create horizontal scrolling

Tags: css, flexbox, horizontal-scrolling

The scenario here is that I am importing a React header component that uses Flexbox onto a page that is wrapped in a lot of Flexbox css. I **only have have access to `myDiv`** (and can create as many divs as I want wrapped around it), but I am struggling with getting the header component to either truncate or wrap onto multiple lines.

My problems are solved if I specify a specific width of the page in pixels, but is there some way to tell the header component not to expand outside the space it is given? **This also needs to work in IE11**.

Would love some tips on how to debug this scenario. Thanks!

```css
.myDiv { // Can edit this class

}
.outerContainer3 { // Cannot edit this class
  margin-top: 0;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  display: flex;
}

.outerContainer2 { // Cannot edit this class
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.outerContainer1 { // Cannot edit this class
  position: relative;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.headerContainer2 { // Cannot edit this class
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.headerContainer1 { // Cannot edit this class
  min-width: 0%;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  width: 100%;
}

.header { // Cannot edit this class
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerContainer3">
  <div class="outerContainer2">
    <div class="outerContainer1">
      <div>
        <div>
          <div class="myDiv">
            <div class="headerContainer2">
              <div class="headerContainer1">
                <h1 class="header">asdfkasdjlfkasdjfla sjdlfkja sldkfj alskfj lskdjf laskdjf laskjf akjf lsakfjs lak jfkjflakj flkajds lakj f</h1>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: add `width: 100%;` on `.outerContainer1`

Comment: Unfortunately I can't edit the css of `outerContainer1`

Comment: There's no css you can apply to `.myDiv` that would solve it, other than a fixed width or `100vw`, the problem is coming from the ancestors or `.myDiv`, they don't control the width to be 100% of the viewport, so if the children decide to go rouge on their width, they'll be able to do so. since you're using `react` i would suggest that you apply a width to `.myDiv` with it.

Comment: Damn that sucks, I was hoping there would be some magic solution. Someone else deleted their answer which was to remove `white-space: nowrap;` from `.header` (which works), is there any way to do that without editing `.header` directly and not knowing what the class name of `.header` would be?

Comment: `.myDiv h1` this will select all `h1` elements inside `.myDiv`, but if there's only one it will be that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're able to add some css, then this one could help you.

**Update**:
I've added the 'position: absolute;' to the rule in this way the h1 element is not expanding out of the div element and it's working in the IE.

Also you're possibly interested in the property '**word-wrap**' with the value '**break-word**'. This should help you to wrap the very very long words(or urls) without the white-space.

```css
.myDiv { // Can edit this class

}
.myDiv > div > div > h1 {
  white-space: inherit;
  position: absolute;
}
.outerContainer3 { // Cannot edit this class
  margin-top: 0;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  display: flex;
}

.outerContainer2 { // Cannot edit this class
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.outerContainer1 { // Cannot edit this class
  position: relative;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.headerContainer2 { // Cannot edit this class
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.headerContainer1 { // Cannot edit this class
  min-width: 0%;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  width: 100%;
}

.header { // Cannot edit this class
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerContainer3">
  <div class="outerContainer2">
    <div class="outerContainer1">
      <div>
        <div>
          <div class="myDiv">
            <div class="headerContainer2">
              <div class="headerContainer1">
                <h1 class="header">asdfkasdjlfkasdjfla sjdlfkja sldkfj alskfj lskdjf laskdjf laskjf akjf lsakfjs lak jfkjflakj flkajds lakj f</h1>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Although it turns out this doesn't work in IE11, any ideas on whether there's a bug with that?

Comment: Actually 'white-space' should work in IE too, but seems it have some problems(Hey as everything on IE!)... Anyway I've updated the answer with adding 'position: absolute' in the style rule. In this way the h1 element width is not going out of the div element and 'white-space: inherit' is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Add a max width to outerContainer1 and to the myDiv elements.

```css
.myDiv {
    max-width: 100%;
}
.outerContainer3 {
  margin-top: 0;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  display: flex;
}

.outerContainer2 {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.outerContainer1 {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.headerContainer2 {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.headerContainer1 {
  min-width: 0%;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  width: 100%;
}

.header {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerContainer3">
  <div class="outerContainer2">
    <div class="outerContainer1">
      <div>
        <div>
          <div class="myDiv">
            <div class="headerContainer2">
              <div class="headerContainer1">
                <h1 class="header">asdfkasdjlfkasdjfla sjdlfkja sldkfj alskfj lskdjf laskdjf laskjf akjf lsakfjs lak jfkjflakj flkajds lakj f</h1>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't edit the css of `outerContainer`